# Running wc(word count) command in C

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to run `wc` linux command from a C program but I am not getting the desired output.

```
int main() {

    pid_t pid = fork();
    
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("Error forking process");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (pid == 0) {

        int fid = open("testtxt.txt", O_RDONLY);
        if (fid == -1) {
            perror("Error opening file");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        close(0);
        dup2(fid, STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fid);
        
        execlp("wc", "wc", (char *)NULL);
        
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As per my understanding I am creating a child process using `fork()` and in the `pid==0` else if block I am setting the `stdin` for the child process as **texttxt.txt** file. Then I am using `execlp` to run the `wc` command on the file. And as the `stdout` is still the terminal it should print the word count of the provided file on the terminal. I have `wait(NULL)` in the else clause to stop the parent process during the execution of child process.

But the output I get on terminal is not what I expect.
The output I get is `1 14 78`

Can someone please explain me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What output did you expect? That you're getting a sensible looking output suggests it works. What do you get if you just type `wc testtxt.txt` in your terminal?

Comment: What is the content of `texttxt.txt`? What output is expected?

Comment: Actually, what do you get from `wc <testtxt.txt` in the terminal, which will be different from `wc testtxt.txt`

Comment: I thought wc should return the number of characters in the given file

Comment: `wc -m` will do that. Read the man page for it.

Comment: Seems like all the `fork()` and `dup2()` and `execlp()` were irrelevant. You just ran the wrong command.

Comment: Your question suggests you expected a word count. Your comment suggests you want a character count. Very confusing.

Comment: Why do you think `1 14 78` is wrong? You need to provide the file you used for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You should also test for `execlp()` failure, which could happen if the `wc` binary cannot be found in one of the directories specified in the `PATH` variable.

The output `1 14 78` indicates the file **texttxt.txt** contains a single line with 14 words for a total of 78 bytes.

If you want just the number of words, specify a command line argument `"-w"`:

```
      execlp("wc", "wc", "-w", (char *)NULL);
```

By default, `wc` outputs the number of line, words and bytes. You can specify other outputs with these command line options:

- `-c` or `--bytes`: print the byte counts
- `-m` or `--chars`: print the character counts
- `-l` or `--lines`: print the newline counts
- `-w` or `--words`: print the word counts

Comment: I edited my code to "/usr/bin/wc" but still its giving the same output i.e. "1 14 78"

Comment: `execlp()` searches for executable in `PATH` environment variable.